# Laravel request validation on array

Tags: laravel, validation, request

Lets say I submit this form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="emails[]">
    <input type="text" name="emails[]">
    <input type="text" name="emails[]">
    <input type="text" name="emails[]">
    <input type="text" name="emails[]">
</form>
```

How do I then validate that at least **one** (anyone) of the `$request->emails[]` is filled?

I have tried this - however it does not work:

```
 $request->validate([
     'emails' => 'array|min:1',
     'emails.*' => 'nullable|email',
 ]);
```

Laravel 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To meet your requirement, you may need custom rule

First create a rule, `php artisan make:rule YourRuleName`

inside `YourRuleName.php`

```
 public function passes($attribute, $value)
 {
     foreach(request()->{$attribute} as $email) {
         // if not null, then just return true. 
         // its assume in arrays some item have values
         if ($email) { // use your own LOGIC here
             return true;
         }
     }

     return false;
 }
```

Then,

```
 $request->validate([
     'emails' => [new YourRuleName],
 ]);
```

Comment: `if($email)` will not give correct results if the user passes spaces as value

Comment: its just example tho.. replace with your logic in that..

Comment: Thanks @ZeroOne. The final solution as above + 

          'candidate_email' => [new MinOneArrayFilled],
            'candidate_email.*' => ['email', 'nullable']

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$request->validate([
    'emails' => 'array|required',
    'emails.*' => 'email',
]);
```

Cordially

Comment: Nope  - it "requires" all fields to be set.

Comment: wich field are you talking ? I can see only one email field in your form.